# Why does this PHP code give "undefined index"?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have this code:

```
print_r(array_keys($variables));
if (array_key_exists('form', $variables)) {
 print "YES!";
}
$imgs = $variables['form']['field_images'];
```

It's a part of the code that I use to theme a form page in Drupal. YES is printed out, however, drupal reports undefined index for that. Thanks for your generous help

Comment: Are you sure it's not reporting that `field_images` is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

`$variables['form']` does exist, but `$variables['form']['field_images]` probably not. That's why you get the notice about `undefined index`.

So you should make sure that the subkey also exists before you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

as an example implemenation of [Ikke`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11717228/4833) answer:

```
if ( !array_key_exists('form', $variables) ) {
    echo 'missing parameter form';
}
else if ( !array_key_exists('field_images', $variables['form']) ) {
        echo 'missing parameter field_images';
}
else {
    $imgs = $variables['form']['field_images'];     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

PHP throws the notice. You can add an isset() or !empty() check to avoid the error, like such:

```
if(isset($variables)) ) && !empty($variables)) ))
{

    if (array_key_exists('form', $variables)) {
     print "YES!";
    }
    $imgs = $variables['form']['field_images'];

}
```